# References for logarithmic geometry

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, log-geometry

Hi everyone,

I'm looking for a systematical introduction to (or treatment of) logarithmic structures on schemes. I am reading Kato's article ("Logarithmic structures of Fontaine-Illusie") at the moment, but I would like to have a more detailed source that goes through or gives an overview of the constructions of classical scheme theory that have analogs in the log-setup.
Are there any articles/books that in your opinion are required reading if I want to learn about log-geometry? What are beautiful examples of applications of this machinery?

Comment: It seems Illusie has a few articles. 

Comment: Also look up Olsson.

Comment: there is a review of log-syntomic site in ''Torsion étale and crystalline cohomologies'' (Breuil, Messing), Astérisque 279, 2002, 81-124. But I don't know if it is what you want. I know practically nothing about log geometry...

Comment: at the moment I'm trying to learn the basics, but the goal will be to study the log-infinitesimal site.

Comment: Thanks for the good references, all answers were very helpful. I accepted Thanos' because of making Illusie's notes available, I wouldn't even know where to look for them otherwise.

Comment: Olsson gave 5 lectures on log geometry in Pisa a few summers ago, which Anton kindly live-texed: http://math.berkeley.edu/~anton/written/AspectsModuli/MO.pdf

Comment: Is there any new work on this subject (i.e. an attempt to understand normal crossing varieties) in a purely geometric way, i.e. something which avoids monoides and is focused on complex algebraic varieties, rather than formal scheme theoretic point of view. The only work of this type which I know is the thesis of Friedman, which is quit old.

Comment: @DavidZureick-Brown The link seems to be broken. Where can I find that?

Comment: @etairi http://stacky.net/wiki/index.php?title=Course_notes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I put up some old notes by Illusie [here](http://math.harvard.edu/~tdp/Illusie-Log.geometry.lecture.notes-single-page.pdf) for you; they're very detailed and treat log smoothness, the log de Rham complex, and other topics in their second exposé. They're my favourite first reference.

There is also Ogus's book, the latest draft of which is [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/preprints/log_book/logbook.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the book by Ogus looks very nice, and I'll definitely have a look at Illusie's notes.

Comment: @Thanos: I tried to open the notes you mentioned, but it appeared as a broken link. Did you already delete them? I would appreciate if you can help me to reach those notes, thanks :)

Comment: @Yujia: link reactivated!

Comment: The link is broken again

Comment: Is there somewhere else to find these notes? What about the writing by Pottharst mentioned at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/logarithmic+geometry?

Comment: @DavidCorwin For Ogus' book, which would be unfortunately no longer legally accessible online. See https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/logpagenew.html

Comment: The link to Illusie's notes is broken. It's a shame -- I found them quite helpful. Were they ever in more published, citable form?

Answer (score 8):

One standard reference is

Luc Illusie. An overview of the work of K. Fujiwara, K. Kato, and C. Nakayama on logarithmic
 ́etale cohomology. Ast ́erisque, (279):271–322, 2002. Cohomologies p-adiques et applications
arithm ́etiques, II.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that Arthur Ogus has been working on a book on this topic for many years.  I don't know if it (or at least some version of it) has appeared.  (I looked on his web-page and found what looks like a nice set of slides from a talk, 62 pages of them, but no actual book.)

In any event, Ogus certainly has many papers on the topic.  My recommendation, if you have gotten through Kato's article, would be to start reading some of Ogus's and others' articles.
A lot of them are reasonably foundational, and should be accessible if you have Kato's article under your belt.   In addition to the names already mentioned in the various comments and answers, Kisin has a couple of nice papers using log-schemes on his web-page.

One nice application, arithmetic in nature (and the first place that I saw log schemes), is the paper of Coleman--Voloch on companion forms.  Kisin's paper on the Galois action on the
prime-to-p-etale fundamental group is another nice application to arithmetic geometry that I know of.

Comment: Background stuff: Ogus gave a course on this stuff in Berkeley in the 1990s and I think he was already working on the book then :-) Coleman once told me that he was motivated by the case of companion forms which Gross hadn't dealt with, and I think he said he had a proof without log schemes just for this case, and then Felipe came along, added the log schemes, and re-did the general case :-) 

Answer (score 4):

Danny Gillam at Brown also has some nice notes on his webpage.

Comment: Where? I cannot find them.

Comment: They're at http://www.math.brown.edu/~wgillam/lognotes.pdf

Comment: The link seems to be broken